# How many bytes of entropy are recommended for seeding a mnemonic phrase?

Tags: private-key, mnemonic-seed

If I wanted to generate a 12 word mnemonic, how many additional bytes of entropy is recommended I use?

Comment: How do you mean "additional"? The words are your entropy.

Comment: To note: you should **not** choose your words, you should generate entropy in as random a way as possible, and then that entropy will be encoded into a mnemonic seed phrase. Humans are very bad/unreliable sources of entropy!

Comment: Sorry I meant in total how much entropy is considered secure for generating the mnemonic phrase?